# Geometric interpretation of Lagrange's linear equation and its solution

Tags: differential-equations, linear-pde

What is the geometric meaning of the Lagrange's linear equation, $$P\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} + Q \dfrac {\partial z}{\partial y}= R \\Pp+ Qq= R$$ where $P$,$Q$,and $R$  are functions of $x\,$,$\,y\,$ and $z$. How do we arrive at the solution of the same? I've got a feeling that it has something to do with *direction cosines* and stuff. But I just cant relate them with the equation. We are being taught just to write the auxiliary equation, $$\dfrac{dx}{P}=\dfrac{dy}{Q}=\dfrac{dz}{R}$$ group, and integrate or find two set of "multipliers" and finally write $\phi (u,v)=0$. I've got no clue, what's happening behind the curtains.

P.S: I'm relatively new to the subject.

Comment: You’re asking a good question, but this isn’t the right place to ask. Try math.stackexchange.com or the math or learnmath subreddits.

Comment: @DeaneYang I've tried every platform possible :( Nobody answered, thanks for responding. :)